# How to display an image and edit the image using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Actually i am trying to dispaly an image in frontend nut it is displaying only name while iam fetching the records from databaseWhile uploading the image iam saving the images in one folder.Here is my code.

Controller:

```
 public function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 5,

    );
    $users = $this->paginate('User');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="users form">
<h1>Users</h1>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('image','Images');?></th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                     
    <?php $count=0; ?>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>              
    <?php $count ++;?>
    <?php if($count % 2): echo '<tr>'; else: echo '<tr class="zebra">' ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <td><?php echo  $user['User']['image']; ?></td>
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images

Comment: I need to fetch the image from the folder right if i will fetch the image from database it will display only name can anyone help me regarding this actually iam new to cakephp.

Comment: what is name of your image folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>
<?php 
$imgPath = WWW_ROOT.DS.'img'.DS.'YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_HERE'.DS.$user['User']['image'];

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imgPath);

echo  $this->Html->image('YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_HERE/'.$user['User']['image']);

echo $widht;
echo $height;
// ...

?>
</td>
```

Comment: Its working cant we give width and height of the image while we are fetching

Comment: are you store width and height of the image in db ??

Comment: no while fetching the image i need to give width and height

Comment: i add some example, use php getimagesize() method, http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php